# Python array visualizer for debugging

Tags: python

I'm working with image processing which means I'm doing operations on large matrices. I'm trying to debug which means I need to explore the elements, but it's a real pain doing it with print statements. Is there some kind of python plugin that will let me view arrays in a GUI for the purpose of debugging?

Comment: If you are doing image processing, why are you not showing *the images*, instead?

Comment: A number of the operations I do produce matrices of complex numbers or negative numbers - which aren't easily visualisable. I need access to the raw numbers themselves to check they make sense vs calculations by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes just use the python debugger and put a break point

or use something like `q`

`$ easy_install q`

```
import q
my_array = numpy.arange(1000)
q.d() #open a terminal where you have access to my_array
```

you will see something like below

```
Python console opened by q.d() in <some_module>
>>> print my_array[5]
```

you can also use pill to generate an image from the array (not sure if it will work right without tweaking)

```
>>> import Image
>>> img = Image.fromarray(my_array, 'RGB')
>>> img.save('test.png')
```

Comment: q.d() was just the ticket! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

However, if you would like to display numpy array as an image, you can use OpenCV Image Viewer Plugin, which I've just released.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14371-opencv-image-viewer

[image]